# How to type the callback of a promise in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I can type the callback for .then in my promise, currently I am temporary using `any` bit I would like to use `string` or similar.

Any idea how to type my function md5?

```
export const md5 = (path: string) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const hash = createHash("sha1");
    const rs = createReadStream(path);
    rs.on("error", reject);
    rs.on("data", chunk => hash.update(chunk));
    rs.on("end", () => resolve(hash.digest("hex")));
  });


  it("should hash md5 a file", () => {
    // error here on hash:string, if I use instead any it works
    const m = md5(fileName).then((hash: string) => {
      assert.strictEqual(m, "4738e449ab0ae7c25505aab6e88750da");
    });
```

Error I receive:

```
Argument of type '(hash: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.
  Types of parameters 'hash' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  });
```

Comment: Try using `new Promise<string>(...`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider specifying the return Promise type directly `new Promise<string>`:

```
export const md5 = (path: string) =>
  new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    const hash = createHash("sha1");
    const rs = createReadStream(path);
    rs.on("error", reject);
    rs.on("data", chunk => hash.update(chunk));
    rs.on("end", () => resolve(hash.digest("hex")));
  });
```

Please also check for an error in your test, replace `m` with `hash`:

```
assert.strictEqual(hash, "4738e449ab0ae7c25505aab6e88750da");
```

Answer (score 1):

Either give the Promise a generic type parameter, give your `md5` method a return type, or both:

```
export const md5 = (path: string): Promise<string> =>
  new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    const hash = createHash("sha1");
    const rs = createReadStream(path);
    rs.on("error", reject);
    rs.on("data", chunk => hash.update(chunk));
    rs.on("end", () => resolve(hash.digest("hex")));
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

All you are missing is 'return'. Change to this:

```
export const md5 = (path: string) =>
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const hash = createHash("sha1");
        const rs = createReadStream(path);
        rs.on("error", reject);
        rs.on("data", chunk => hash.update(chunk));
        rs.on("end", () => resolve(hash.digest("hex")));
    });
```

Comment: It's an anonymous arrow function. It doesn't need a return statement, and it's not valid unless the body of the function is wrapped in {}. This code would cause a `'{' expected` error